# Compare latest and earliest dates in mysql table and display changes only

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called archive:

```
| staff_id |   longname  | username | projectNo |  title   | process | creation_time |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ch) |  2017-01-16   |
|    03    | James Bond  |   James  |    1702   | project2 | BGD(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1702   | project2 | CGI(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | BGD(ch) |  2017-03-16   |
|    03    | James Bond  |   James  |    1702   | project2 | BGD(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1702   | project2 | CGI(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
```

I want to choose latest date and earliest date then compare this two queries and display only those rows which have been changed. So from table above it should display:

```
| staff_id |   longname  | username | projectNo |  title   | process | creation_time |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | BGD(ch) |  2017-03-16   |
```

As only this row was changed.

I know how to choose earliest date in queries:

```
SELECT staff_id, longname, username, title, process, creation_time FROM archived
WHERE creation_time IN (SELECT min(creation_time) FROM archived)
```

And latest date:

```
SELECT staff_id, longname, username, title, process, creation_time FROM archived
WHERE creation_time IN (SELECT max(creation_time) FROM archived)
```

The question is how can i compare queries and display only changes?

### EDIT

Ok so what i have is table archive:

```
| staff_id |   longname  | username | projectNo |  title   | process | creation_time |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ch) |  2017-01-16   |
|    03    | James Bond  |   James  |    1702   | project2 | BGD(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1702   | project2 | CGI(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | BGD(ch) |  2017-03-16   |
|    03    | James Bond  |   James  |    1702   | project2 | BGD(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1702   | project2 | CGI(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
```

Table updates every day on 00:00:00. So latest day will be different. What I want is to take rows with first date:

```
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ch) |  2017-01-16   |
|    03    | James Bond  |   James  |    1702   | project2 | BGD(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1702   | project2 | CGI(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
```

And with latest date:

```
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | BGD(ch) |  2017-03-16   |
|    03    | James Bond  |   James  |    1702   | project2 | BGD(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1702   | project2 | CGI(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
```

Then compare row by row. For example:

```
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
```

with

```
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1701   | project1 | ANM(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
```

Rows are the same so I dont need to display them as

```
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1702   | project2 | CGI(ld) |  2017-01-16   |
```

with

```
|    01    |   John Doe  |   John   |    1702   | project2 | CGI(ld) |  2017-03-16   |
```

These rows also same. So the only row I want to print is

```
| staff_id |   longname  | username | projectNo |  title   | process | creation_time |
|    02    | Aaron Jones |   Aaron  |    1701   | project1 | BGD(ch) |  2017-03-16   |
```

becaude its different.

Comment: Which field indicates a change? process field?

Comment: @ObjectManipulator projectNo, title and process fields

Comment: what is data type for creation_time? is datetime or just date?

Comment: @sukalogika datetime

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select tmax.*
from yourtable tmax
inner join (
    select staff_id, max(`creation_time`) as maxtime, min(`creation_time`) as mintime
    from yourtable
    group by staff_id
) t on tmax.staff_id = t.staff_id and tmax.creation_time = t.maxtime
inner join yourtable tmin
on t.staff_id = tmin.staff_id and tmin.creation_time = t.mintime
where tmax.projectNo <> tmin.projectNo or tmax.title <> tmin.title or tmax.`process` <> tmin.`process`
```

See sqlfiddle [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/75be43/1) here.

Subquery will fetch max time and min time for each staff_id, then join your table twice with staff_id and max, min time, in where statement is your criteria.

Comment: please check [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/25435/1) i added a bit more data. why i got this two rows. rows are the same except creation_time field. But its still displayed.

Comment: Your time is: 00:00:00 in all data row, you can try insert unique creation_time

Comment: @sukalogika time is always the same. as there is an event in database which insert data to table each day at 00:00:00. so only date changes

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy For this situation, several records in same day, which record do you want to compare or get?

Comment: @Forward i want to get only that record which is different from previous one comparing by date. so it means system should compare row with the similar row but different date and if its changed display it.

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy Seems to be different from op, re-edit your post, let's know what exactly you want to do.

Comment: @Forward i edited table and added same names with different projects. but my desired output is still the same. i only want to get that row which is different from same row with different time

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy Nope, I still do not know the logic what you post in op.

Comment: @Forward please see edit. hope its more clear now. thanks

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy So you compare unit is `staff_id` and `projectNo`?

Comment: @Forward `staff_id` `projectNo` and `process` as there is can be still same projectNo but with different process